# How can I use list comprehension to get some data from another list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

Hello I have the following list :

```
a = [{'Hello':5, 'id':[{'cat':'billy', 'dog': 'Paul'}, {'cat':'bill', 'dog': 'Pau'}]},
     {'Hello':1, 'id':[{'cat':'Harry', 'dog': 'Peter'}, {'cat':'Hary', 'dog': 'Pete'}]}]
```

and I would like to build the following list (using list comprehensions):

```
b = ['billy', 'bill', 'Hary', 'Harry']
```

I tried these without success:

```
[x for y in a for b in y['id'] for x in b]
[x for y in a for b in y['id'] for x in b['cat']]
```

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, specifically?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a double loop:

```
[x['cat'] for y in a for x in y['id'] if type(x) is  dict]
```

you have to :

1. Get values in the a list as a list (for y in a)
2. get the 'id' in y (for x in y['id'])
3. Skip the string 'eat' by filtering for dictionary (if type(x) is dict)
4. Access the 'cat'

If you dict x, has multiple values, you can use

```
[x.values() for y in a for x in y['id'] if type(x) is  dict]]
```

Comment: Thank you but I forgot the key dog... and now it does not work :/ Could you help me please ? :)

Comment: you can use x.values , this will give you back dict_values

Comment: Why would OP want to use a "double" (nested) loop, where a single loop solution is available (and much more readable)?

Comment: for readability, I find it hard to find out what's going on in d['id'][0]['cat'] @DeepSpace

Comment: Actually I did a mistake in my list. Here is correct. Could you help me please ? :) Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
b = [x['id'][0]['cat'] for x in a]
```

Each element of `a` is a dict that looks like

```
{
    'Hello': ...,
    'id': [
        {
            'cat': ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I forgot the key dog... and now it does not work :/ Could you help me please ? :)

Comment: My solution doesn't assume that `cat` is the only key in that dict; the presence or absence of `dog` shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Actually I did a mistake in my list. Here is correct. Could you help me please ? :) Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following list-comprehension for this:

```
>>> a = [{'Hello':5, 'id':[{'cat':'billy', 'dog': 'Paul'}, {'cat':'bill', 'dog': 'Pau'}]},
     {'Hello':1, 'id':[{'cat':'Harry', 'dog': 'Peter'}, {'cat':'Hary', 'dog': 'Pete'}]}]

>>> [y['cat'] for x in a for y in x['id']]
['billy', 'bill', 'Harry', 'Hary']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use build-in functions `itemgetter` and  `chain` (from itertools module)

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import itemgetter

list(map(itemgetter('cat'), chain(*map(itemgetter('id'), a))))
```

**output:**

```
['billy', 'bill', 'Harry', 'Hary']
```

or you can use a list comprehension with 2 `for` loops inside, first to iterate over all the `dict` elements in the list and the second to iterate the innermost lists and grab the element from the key 'cat':

```
[i['cat'] for d in a for i in d['id']]
```